# First_day last_day starting from January

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following query, which is working as expected. My question how can I get the output starting from January for a specific year ie 2023 without hard coding a value.

```
SELECT   TRUNC (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, (LEVEL - 1)), 'MM') FIRST_DAY,
             LAST_DAY (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, (LEVEL - 1))) LAST_DAY
      FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY   LEVEL <= 12;

FIRST_DAY    LAST_DAY
01-NOV-22.    30-NOV-22
01-DEC-22     31-DEC-22
01-JAN-23     31-JAN-23
01-FEB-23     28-FEB-23
01-MAR-23     31-MAR-23
01-APR-23     30-APR-23
01-MAY-23     31-MAY-23
01-JUN-23     30-JUN-23
01-JUL-23     31-JUL-23
01-AUG-23     31-AUG-23
01-SEP-23     30-SEP-23
01-OCT-23     31-OCT-23
```

Comment: Your `LAST_DAY` column has the time component of the current time (and not midnight) [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/i-72_ZDr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific year (2023), how is your query supposed to know it unless you "hardocde" it? It doesn't have to be "2023" literally but e.g. "next year, according to `SYSDATE`") such as in this example:

```
SQL> with starting_date (datum) as
  2    (select add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy'), 12) from dual)
  3  select          add_months(datum, level - 1)  first_day,
  4         last_day(add_months(datum, level - 1)) last_day
  5  from starting_date
  6  connect by level <= 12;

FIRST_DAY LAST_DAY
--------- ---------
01-JAN-23 31-JAN-23
01-FEB-23 28-FEB-23
01-MAR-23 31-MAR-23
01-APR-23 30-APR-23
01-MAY-23 31-MAY-23
01-JUN-23 30-JUN-23
01-JUL-23 31-JUL-23
01-AUG-23 31-AUG-23
01-SEP-23 30-SEP-23
01-OCT-23 31-OCT-23
01-NOV-23 30-NOV-23
01-DEC-23 31-DEC-23

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks!! That is exactly what I was looking to do. I should have worded my question better